# Sample functions of stochastic processes violate Dirichlet conditions. Why?

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-transform

Suppose we have a real-valued periodic function that satisfies the Dirichlet conditions. In this case its Fourier series converges.  With some expedients this concept can be extended also to non-periodic functions.

Suppose now that we have a function that is a realization of a stochastic process. It is commonly argued that in this case the function violates the Dirichlet conditions so that its Fourier transform no longer converges. For this reason it becomes necessary to define the correlation function. Indeed, it satifies the Dirichlet conditions and its Fourier transform is said power spectral density (psd). Therefore, spectral information of the function are carried from the psd.

I have two questions on this topic:

1. Why can't I calculate the Fourier transform of the function directly? Which conditions are violated by a realization of a stochastic process? and why?
2. Why are the correlation function and the power spectral density so important?

Thank you

Comment: One example:  white noise (flat power spectrum).

Comment: Which conditions are violated by white noise?

Comment: I am not sure how it fits into your question.  Auto correlation is delta function.  No Fourier series.

Comment: If you consider a sample function of a white noise process, then you have a specific time history. In general, in order to extract information from it, you need to calculate its autocorrelation and then its power spectral density (which can be computed as the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation). My question is: which characteristics of this time history does not allow to calculate its Fourier transform directly (namely, avoiding the autocorrelation computation)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question.  When I worked in this area, it never came up.

Comment: ok, thank you anyway!